# Adding C/C++ language to Eclipse Oxygen IDE for Java Developers

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-oxygen

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen.1 IDE for Java Developers 64 bit and I want to add the C/C++ language to it so I can write and compile code for my C Language class using only one IDE. When I go to install new software am I supposed to be installing the development tools for under the programming language tab or from the CDT tab or both? The tools under the Programming Language tab are version 9.3.2 and the tools under CDT tab are version 9.3.0. I'm confused as to which ones I'm supposed to install. Also if anyone could help me with the installation of MinGW. I'm running Windows 10 on a 64 bit operating system. And I'm not sure as to how I can get the latest version of MinGW for 64 bit OS. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  The C++ language requires a C++ compiler.  A C++ compiler may be able to compile the C language.  A C compiler will not successfully compile C++ programs.

Comment: Not sure if it matters anymore, but out of paranoia I recommend installing mingw before the CDT. On mingw I tend toward this one: http://www.msys2.org/ but you have to follow the instructions really carefully.

Comment: Am I able to get one for each of them? I would like to be able to code in both C for my school projects and C++ for my video game projects.

Comment: Mingw will offer you both. Along with Fortran and a few dozen other languages, if I remember correctly.

Comment: If you are under Windows, make yourself a favor and use Visual Studio (C++) Community as your IDE. It's free and it will let you evade from configurations or messing with MinGW. I'm assuming from your post that you have no special requirements, just "write and compile code for C using only one IDE"

Comment: In case you want to write C/C++ code for Arduino or compatible systems, just install the [Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-c-ide-arduino) and use the Arduino Downloads Manager to download the right compiler for the board.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a combined IDE. I use one that combines the Eclipse SDK, including Java and a bunch of other things all in one. It's a bit clunky to do but can be done. Just go to the Help -> Install New Software... menu item and bring up the install dialog.

First install one of them, Java or C/C++. Then after launching it, select the "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen" item in the "Work with:" selector. Then find the other IDE components you would like in the list and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I had Oxygen with java and pydev but experienced great difficulty adding cdt yesterday. I have some good reasons for keeping Oxygen instead of upgrading (older code and even OS compatibility since I'm still running High Sierra, again there are reasons for doing that). One key is finding the url given above download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen . However, my install would still not work,  for some unknown reason.

Here is the important part of my comment. Installs and updates can take forever if you don't uncheck the box on the install page which says this:

```
Contact all update sites during install to find required software
```

It is a known bug, that it is checked by default, but never to be fixed. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340298

Also this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340298 was applied to cdt 9.3 if you get the pty error trying to compile.